# Determining the filetype of a file in C

Tags: c, unix, file-type

I am trying to figure out the file type of a file, without using external libs or the "file" command.

I have viewed a number of posts and threads, and they point to using the stat() function (unix man stat) and playing with the "st_mode" from the stat struct.

But I have no idea how to do this, nor am I able to find a good example of doing it.

For example the program takes in a file F, I want to be able to read F similar to the program below and give similar output.  And the filetype of F is a PDF, but it does not have the extension on it.

FURTHER EXAMPLE:  If I have foo.pdf, but I changed the extension to *.png (foo.png) I can pass my program "foo.png" and say it is infact a .pdf file.

When a file is created, it makes a "magic number", example with a PDF, the  magic number of PDF files start with "%PDF" (hex 25 50 44 46)."

How can I use the magic number to figure out the filetype.

I understand some type of table will need to be made at my end, to support files.  And I am only doing a small handful <10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void errorInput()
{   
    fprintf(stderr, "\nYou have received this message due to an error. \n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Please type 'filetype <file>' to properly execute the program.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Thank you and have a fine day! \n\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char command[128];

  if (argc == 2)
  {
    strcpy(command, "file ");
    strcat(command, argv[1]);
    system(command);
  }
  else
  {
    errorInput();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: *"I am trying to figure out the file type of a file"* What exactly do you mean "the file type"? Are you trying to determine if it is e.g. a PDF file versus an EXE or a BMP? There is no simple way to do this. You have to use a database of identifying features, e.g. `libmagic`, which `file` uses. Don't try to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Does "without using external libs" also include `file`s own list of `magic` signatures? Then you must find file specifications for all types that you want to recognize and implement the check yourself. It's not even very hard or anything ... just a whole load of work.

Comment: "Are you trying to determine if it is e.g. a PDF file versus an EXE or a BMP?"

Yes, exactly it.

Comment: The short answer is open the file, read X number of characters and compare those to the known magic numbers/header of known file types. That is what all the comments/answers have been alluding to.

Comment: The magic numbers are defined in `linux/magic.h` and `a.out.h` in RedHat flavors and probably in `exec.h` in others.

Answer (score 4):

Like Jonathon Reinhart Pointed, don't try to reinvent the wheel use `libmagic`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <magic.h>

int main(void) {
  struct magic_set *magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME|MAGIC_CHECK);
  magic_load(magic,NULL);

  printf("Output1: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"ValgrindOut.xml"));
  printf("Output2: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"program"));
  printf("Output3: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"Chapter9.pdf"));
  printf("Output4: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"test.txt"));
  printf("Output5: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"linux-3.17.tar.xz"));
  printf("Output6: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz"));
  printf("Output7: '%s'\n",magic_file(magic,"/home/michi"));

  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -o program program.c -lmagic
```

Output:

> ```
> Output1: 'application/xml; charset=us-ascii'
> Output2: 'application/x-executable; charset=binary'
> Output3: 'application/pdf; charset=binary'
> Output4: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
> Output5: 'application/x-xz; charset=binary'
> Output6: 'application/gzip; charset=binary'
> Output7: 'inode/directory; charset=binary'
> ```

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to include sys/stat.h

Next, you need to declare a struct stat in your code:

```
struct stat s
```

Next, you pass a pointer to your stat structure along with the file/object name:

```
returnval = stat("filename", &s);
```

Check the return value, you'll get < 0 on error. If no error the object/file exists, we can use a macro function to determine the file type:

```
if (S_ISREG(s.st_mode))
    /* Regular text file... */
else if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))
    /* Is a directory.... */
```

I suggest you have a look at the man page (man 3 stat) and it will give you all of the types that st_type may potentially be (it can be used to identify files, directories, block devices, sym links, etc)

Another very useful member of the stat struct is st_size which gives you a files size in bytes.

ETA - the stat() system call won't tell you if a file is a PDF or anything like that - normally we'd use the extension, if there is no extension and you're trying to identify specific file formats then stat() won't be of much use to you.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help the OP determine if he has a PDF file or not, like he mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. OP wants to detect whether the file is PDF, txt, image, etc.

Comment: I know - he did mention stat() and that he couldn't find any examples of how to use it - so I provided one. You're right though my answer is no use to the OP. Much apologies.

Comment: This only applies to Unix-like OSes, while the question is quite clearly platform-agnostic.

Comment: Like I said the OP mentioned stat() and how to use it, - I updated my answer. Is anyone going to actually trry and answer questions or do y'all simply wait in silence and only emerge to offer criticism? I don't believe what the OP WANTS to do can be done so easily, a thorough understanding of the file formats, headers they may include etc would be required. thanks for repeating what two people before you did - constructive.

Comment: Ok maybe my question is a little unclear.

When a file is created, it makes a "magic number", example with a PDF, the  magic number of PDF files start with "%PDF" (hex 25 50 44 46)."

How can I use the magic number to figure out the filetype.

I understand some type of table will need to be made at my end, to support files.  And I am only doing a small handful <10.

Comment: @user3247187 As Johnathon pointed out, there is libmagic.  How about `char *mytable[] = { "%PDF", ..., NULL };` or if you need an offset: `struct table { int off; char *str; }; struct table mytable[] = { {0,"%PDF"}, ..., {0,NULL} };`

Comment: @Nunchy Nice trying to reply, but next time you should really try to answer the question, not just taking some random part because you think you can answer it, even if off topic... Will save you some down votes...

Comment: It might not be the answer to the question OP asked, but it's the answer to the question i searched for, so I'm jolly well going to upvote this.

Comment: Also i tried to edit this answer to make something clearer, and stackoverflow wont allow me to save the edits :(

Answer (score -1):

Most files usually will have a portion called as `Header`/`MetaData`. It is in this portion/segments of the file which will contain details about the file it self.Also, these `Headers/MetaData` Segments will also contain the `Signature` to identify the file type. But be aware most of these `Signatures` will be in an `Hex Signature format`

Example

PDF Signature - `25 50 44 46`(In Hex) or `%PDF` 
JPEG Signature - Start `FF D8` and end of file `FF D9`

So, Basically you need to open the file in a binary format and parse the file structure and compare it to see if it matches with any one of the file types you define in your program.Like suppose you wanna check if it's `pdf` file then you need to first open the file in binary mode then scan the file till you get the `bytcode/hex code` which matches the `bytcode/hex code` of a `pdf` file. Use the `C` `fopen()` function in binary mode i.e `"rb"`.

Or you can open the file normally without binary mode like this,

```
unsigned int data;
data=fgetc(pfile);
```

You might want to look into this for further details,

1. [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)
2. [File Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: well, the numbers aren't really in hex format, they're just numbers, you can look at them any way you want. If you are talking about how the numbers are listed in some reference documentation, then yes, you're correct. It was just written in a slightly ambiguous way. (I'm not the downvote - I would have the integrity to comment if I were)